# PUT request for HTTPS (SSL)

Tags: linux, perl, api

I want to create a HTTPS PUT request, But it is giving me the following error:

```
Error :
    Undefined subroutine &HTTP::Request called at test.pl line 15.
```

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "/usr/cisco/packages/perl/perl-5.16.3/lib/5.16.3";
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request;
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use MIME::Base64;

my $url = 'https://example.com:8443/cli/agentCLI';
my $credentials = encode_base64('username:password');

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new(ssl_opts =>{ verify_hostname => 0});
my $req = HTTP::Request->("PUT",$url, 'Authorization' =>" Basic   $credentials");
my $response = $ua->request($req);
die 'http status: ' . $response->code . '  ' . $response->message
unless ($response->is_success);

my $json_obj = JSON->new->utf8->decode($response->content);
my $output=Dumper($json_obj);

print $output;
```

Comment: Tried to make the question easier to understand and moved the error to the top to increase visibility.

Comment: You have a typing mistake and have simply missed the `new` method name. The statement defining `$req` should look similar to the preceding line defining `$ua`. It happens to us all!

Answer (score 0):

That routine doesn't exist you need to add the new keyword to instantiate the object request

```
my $req = HTTP::Request->new("PUT",$url, 'Authorization' =>" Basic   $credentials");
```

Another option instead of manually placing header yourself is to use the request correctly

Edit for other auth option

```
$req = HTTP::Request->new("PUT", $url);
$req->authorization_basic('username', 'password');
my $response = $ua->request($req);
```

Comment: Erm, what routine doesn't exist? And *“instantiate the object request”* is nonsense.

Comment: It's at the top of the OP question... Undefined subroutine &HTTP::Request called at test.pl line 15. Basically it means Request object isn't a function to be called. It's a factory object

Comment: my $url = 'https://example:8443/cli/agentCLI/test?agent=ud-agt-dev1-05-2';     i have chnaged as my $req = HTTP::Request->new("PUT",$url, 'Authorization' =>" Basic $credentials");...But getting error like Bad header argument at test.pl line 15

Comment: Edited to show easier way to do basic auth should fix header issue @KalaiyarasanSelvaraj

Comment: Thanks... Geohut..its access d url. But now i m getting a error ...malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 ["Test server to agent..."] at test.pl line 21